# Using enumeration classes in EF

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core

I'm using enumeration classes based on [this](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/) article from Jimmy Bogard in my domain model. However, EF treats the classes as entities and wants a key to be defined.

Is there a way to make EF store the values from the enumeration classes like it does it with standard C# enums?

This is how I currently implemented the enumeration class:

```
public class ReservationStatus : Enumeration
{
    public static readonly ReservationStatus Outstanding = new ReservationStatus(0, "Oustanding");
    public static readonly ReservationStatus Paid = new ReservationStatus(1, "Paid");
    public static readonly ReservationStatus Canceled = new ReservationStatus(2, "Canceled");
    public static readonly ReservationStatus Rejected = new ReservationStatus(3, "Rejected");

    private ReservationStatus() { }
    private ReservationStatus(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName) { }
}

public class Reservation : Entity<int>
{
    public ReservationStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using EF 7 RC1.

Comment: Are you try mark as `[key]` `public ReservationStatus Status { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF6 you could configure your `ReservationClass` as [ComplexType](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types), ignore the `DisplayName` property and map `Value` property.

Unfortunately for you, according to [these design meeting notes](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Entity-Framework-Design-Meeting-Notes-June-5,-2014):

> In the initial RTM of EF7 we are **not** planning to enable **complex** and/or **value** types.

In other words, you cannot do that in current EF Core.

Comment: It seems like they have it it in their backlog according to [their roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap) and [this post](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/246), but their is no release date, yet.

Answer (score 8):

For the ones who come across this *well referenced* thread using **EF Core**, I usually store custom type enumerations by its value (aka identifier) in the database using type conversions. This extension method can be used in the method `OnModelCreating` (or a class that implements `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>`):

```
internal static class EnumerationConfiguration
{
    public static void OwnEnumeration<TEntity, TEnum>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TEnum>> property)
        where TEntity : class
        where TEnum : Enumeration
    {
        builder
            .Property(property)
            .HasConversion(x => x.Id, x => Enumeration.FromId<TEnum>(x));
    }
}
```

Afterwards, an enumeration property can be configured as follows:

```
internal class SpecimenConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Specimen>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Specimen> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnEnumeration(x => x.Type);
    }
}
```

The benefits of this approach is that it only stores the identifier (and not the other properties attached to a given derived class of `Enumeration`) and supports subclassing of `Enumeration`.

The downside is an heavily use of reflection through `Enumeration.FromId<TEnum>(x)`. This can be amortized by introducing caching in this method, which is not provided by the linked article of Jimmy Bogard.

Answer (score 1):

For those using EF Core 3.1 there is a better way to do it. The goal is to have a database table with the enumerations listed.

(1) Define how the enumeration table should look like:

```
public virtual DbSet<ReservationStatus> ReservationStatuses { get; set; }
 
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ReservationStatus> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasDefaultValue(1).ValueGeneratedNever().IsRequired();
    builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();
}
```

(2) Define how the value relates in the reservation entity

```
 public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Reservation> builder)
 {
     builder.Property(x => x.ReservationStatusId).IsRequired();
     builder.HasOne(x => x.ReservationStatus)
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReservationStatusId);
 }
```

(3) Seed the enumeration table

```
if (!await RevervationSatuses.AnyAsync())
{
    RevervationSatuses.AddRange(Enumeration.GetAll<RevervationSatus>());
    await SaveChangesAsync();
}
```